# XML tag repetition in JAXB marshalling using EclipseLink MOXy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy, xml-binding

Can someone help me to generate XML with repeated tag using JAXB marshalling using EclipseLink MOXy.

```
@XmlPath("ExecRpt/Pty/@ID") --"ABC"
@XmlPath("ExecRpt/Pty/@ID") --"ABD"
@XmlPath("ExecRpt/Instrmt/@Exch") --"AAA"
```

I am expecting result:

```
 <ExecRpt> <pty ID="ABC"/> <Instrmt Exch="AAA"/><pty ID="ABD"/>  </ExecRpt>
```

Using below approach i am generating from annotated bean to XML.

```
 JAXBContext.createMarshaller()
 Marshaller.marshal()
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how you could map your use case using [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlPath` extension.

**ExecRpt**

You can specify the position of the element that you wish to map to `@XmlPath("Pty[2]/@ID")`.

```java
package forum12052961;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="ExecRpt")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"field1", "field2", "field3"})
public class ExecRpt {

    @XmlPath("Pty[1]/@ID")
    String field1;

    @XmlPath("Instrmt/@Exch")
    String field2;

    @XmlPath("Pty[2]/@ID")
    String field3;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to have a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum12052961;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ExecRpt.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum12052961/input.xml");
        ExecRpt execRpt = (ExecRpt) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(execRpt, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExecRpt>
   <Pty ID="ABC"/>
   <Instrmt Exch="AAA"/>
   <Pty ID="ABD"/>
</ExecRpt>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html